# click on image on react-image-gallery and go fullscreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image

```
import "../../node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import { useRef } from "react";

const images = [
  {
    original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/",
    thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/",
  },
  {
    original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/",
    thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/",
  },
  {
    original: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/",
    thumbnail: "https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/",
  },
];
const Carousel = (props) => {
  const imageGalleryRef = useRef(null);

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    imageGalleryRef.current.toggleFullscreen();
  };

  return (
    <ImageGallery
      items={images}
      showThumbnails={true}
      showFullscreenButton={true}
      showPlayButton={false}
      showBullets={true}
      ref={imageGalleryRef}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

this returns `imageGalleryRef.current.toggleFullscreen is not a function`
but I can run that function from the console and it works, what am I doing wrong?
also is this the best way to implement clicking on the image and going fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `fullScreen` instead of `toggleFullscreen`. As per the [documentation on functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery#functions):

> The following functions can be accessed using refs
>
> - play(): plays the slides
> - pause(): pauses the slides
> - fullScreen(): activates full screen
> - exitFullScreen(): deactivates full screen
> - slideToIndex(index): slides to a specific index
> - getCurrentIndex(): returns the current index